# Slow response Firebase + Python + Raspberry pi

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi

I'm playing around with the firebase_admin python library from Firebase and I've been able to read and write data to a database. However, every write or read function takes around 5 minutes to complete.

Has anyone experienced this? I am using a RPi 2 with Raspbian Stretch (and Python 2).

Thanks for your help!

[Update: Here's the code]

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, db

cred = credentials.Certificate('/home/pi/myCertificate.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
                              'databaseURL':'https://myProject.firebaseio.com/'
})

ref = db.reference('/status/')
ref.update({'current_status':'120grams'})
print('done')
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I just added the comments @DeliriousLettuce, thanks!

Comment: I'm beginning to think there's something wrong with my Pi, since I've have tried 3 different Firebase libraries and they take the same amount of time (several minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out something on this issue. Apparently it is the first database operation that always takes a long time to be done. I placed several more read/write operations after the first one, and they were almost instantly. Maybe it has to do with negotiation or credentials for the first operation.